# displace input row in Access 2003 and SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

Output in Access 2003:

ID  |  *Description*    |   Quantity        |      Title      |        Obj
---   ---------------- --------------------------------------------------

17  |  **6**              |  253000.00        |                 |
18  |  **7**              |  330000.00        |                 |
19  |  **1**              |  340000.00        |     8414        |       69327
22  |  **2**              |  120000.00        |     8414        |       69344
23  |  **3**              |  615000.00        |     8414        |       69327
24  |  **4**              |  320000.00        |     8414        |       69327
25  |  **5**              |  809500.00        |     8414        |       69327

Query :

```
SELECT      TVFundBillDetail.ID ,
            TVFundBillDetail.HID ,
            TVFundBillDetail.Description ,
            TVFundBillDetail.Quantity ,
            TVFundBillDetail.Title ,
            TVTitle.Name TitleName ,
            Obj ,
            TVAllObjects.Name ObjName
     FROM   TVFundBillDetail
            LEFT OUTER JOIN TVTitle ON TVFundBillDetail.Title = TVTitle.Code
            LEFT OUTER JOIN TVAllObjects ON TVFundBillDetail.Obj = TVAllObjects.Code
```

Problem: sequence of input row show in description column. when title and obj is null then displace sequence of input row. application is access 2003 and DBMS is SQL Server 2000

Answer (score 0):

There are probably many ways to achieve this.
For Access, you can simply use `Nz()` in your query, like this:

```
...
Nz(TVFundBillDetail.Title, "    ")
...
```

If `Title` is `NULL`, you'll get 4 spaces (or you can use `"0000"` if you prefer).

For SQL server, an equivalent function is `COALESCE()`:

```
...
COALESCE(TVFundBillDetail.Title, "    ")
...
```

If you're using the query as a normal Qccess query, the first one will work. If you're using a pass-through query, or exposing a SQL Server view, the second one will work.

Comment: @omid, this happens because your `TVFundBillDetail.Title` is not a string but a numerical value and `COALESCE()` will use that type and ends up converting the spaces into `0`. Try to use somthing like `COALESCE(CAST(TVFundBillDetail.Title AS VARCHAR(5)), '    ')`. I can't test these as I don;t have SQL Server installed on my machine right now.